# How to get list of files matching wildcard from a list of directories in msbuild

Tags: msbuild

Give an item list of directories, how can I create an item list of files from those directories that are matching a wildcard?

The following doesn't expand the wildcard:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Files Include="@(Dirs -> '%(Identity)\*.c')" />
</ItemGroup>
```

and the following isn't allowed at all:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Files Include="@(Dirs)\*.c" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

As usual found the answer after posting the questions:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Files Include="%(Dirs.Identity)\*.c" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Excellent easy solution!